# How can I avoid file paths from Jasper report JRXML files

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a template (.jrxml) file. In that I have below code snippet which I used to include an image,

```
<image>
    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="280" height="60" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="d312321a854-323232332-223121d12c2d7f"/>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA["/home/name/app/test/reportTemplates/images/company_logo.JPG"]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

So each time I change the deploying environment I need to change this `/home/name/app/test/reportTemplates/images/company_logo.JPG` path as well.

Any clear way to avoid that design ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "normal" way to this is to use a **parameter** that contains the **base path**

```
<parameter name="IMAGE_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["/home/name/app/test/reportTemplates/images/"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

Set the `defaultValueExpression` so that you can use it in preview (iReport, JasperSoft studio) and `isForPrompting="false"` to avoid that it is asked everytime you preview.

Then in the `imageExpression` use the parameter as base path

```
<imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{IMAGE_DIR} + "company_logo.JPG"]]></imageExpression>
```

When is time to **fill** the report (application run-time) set the `IMAGE_DIR` parameter to the correct deployed path passing it in the parameter map.

es. if you are using java **GUI** you like a relative path to where you are installed

```
File imageDir = new File("images");
String imageAbsolutePath = imageDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator;
```

es. if you have **web application** (jsp/jsf) you like to find the a WEB-INF path of your deployed application

```
ServletContext context = request.getServletContext(); 
String imageAbsolutePath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/images") + "/";
```

Now that we have the absolute path of our image directory we add it to the parameter map that we pass to the fillManager.

```
Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
paramMap.put("IMAGE_DIR",imageAbsolutePath);
//..here goes all the other parameter you may set.
```

and then just pass the parameter map to the fillManager...

**NOTE**: this is an example I do not know how you fill

```
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, paramMap, connection);
```

Comment: this seems working. But I have to wait for a bit before doing this change. Thanks for the support.

Comment: `<imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{IMAGE_DIR} + "company_logo.JPG"]]></imageExpression>` this approach worked for me. Thank you for the support and fruitful answer. :)